# Populating PROGRAM, MODULE, and CLIENT_INFO fields in v$session with some tag when accessed via DB link

Tags: database, oracle, dblink

We are accessing the some objects in Schema2 present in database 2 using database link from Schema1 in database1. 
This specific DBlink will be used by only one application (ApplicationTest).
Currently when we query the V$session from database2 (target DB) the columns PROGRAM, MODULE, and CLIENT_INFO are either null or have some default values.

Clarification Required:
We want to monitor all the applications which are accessing the database2.
Is it possible to populate PROGRAM, MODULE, and CLIENT_INFO fields in v$session with some tag when accessed via DB link?

Thanks in advance for all your help!
Regards,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call `dbms_applicaion_info` on the remote machine (database 2 here) in order to populate these columns.  Normally, the easiest way to do that would be to ensure that you're only accessing the database link via stored procedures and then do something like this where you set the `module` and `action` in database 2's `v$session` before running your query.

```
declare
  l_cnt integer;
begin
  dbms_application_info.set_module@dblink_to_2( 
    module_name => 'DB Link', 
    action_name => 'Reading over link' 
  );

  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from table@dblink_to_2;
  ...
end;
```